# OpenApi Swagger versioning OR archive creating

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I want to trace an OpenApi file releases and be able to access to a content of this file for a specific release.

Assume I create a release for OpenApi file today, so I want to keep the content for this version somewhere. In this way, later, I can check what is delivered for this release.

I thought about something like creating an archive for each OpenApi release.

So for each time I create a release, I save the file in a some folder.
But I have no idea if it's possible and if yes, how can achieve that and with which tool ?

Another question is how I can indicate this content is a release ?

If you have other ideas better than or more feasible than my mine, don't hesitate I still open for your recommendations.